# Angular2/4 router.navigate bug

Tags: angular, typescript

Why am I getting a route enclosed with parenthesis `(profile)`

```
http://localhost:9090/dash/(profile)?h_mTg=0
```

This is what I have inside my click function:

```
this.router
  .navigate(['profile'], { relativeTo: this.route, queryParamsHandling: 'preserve' })
```

Am I missing something in my router navigate?

This is how I defined my routes in this module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DashComponent, children: [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
  ] }
];
```

I even tried to navigate through my `profile` route without the parenthesis and it works perfectly fine

```
http://localhost:9090/dash/profile?h_mTg=0
```

Is this an Angular bug? Is the first time I encountered this, normally this is how I navigate to Angular routes.

Is it because of the cache?

How am going to fix this ?

Comment: When composing 2 routes, you may end up with second route being enclosed with parenthesis. Please take a look at: https://angular.io/guide/router#secondary-route-navigation-merging-routes-during-navigation

Comment: thanks for the link @MaximeFlament